# Object default String conversion method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there a default Object to String conversion method in Ruby just like the Java [Object.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)?

If so, in what operations is it invoked by default? (ex. Object concatenates to a String, puts arguments, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

The method [Object.to_s](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-to_s) is used to return a string representing the object. By default it returns the object’s class and an encoding of the object id. You must overwrite its implementation to write your own string representation